# 2 actors, same parent use case but each one having his own child use case

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a parent use case with some child uses cases, for example:

Parent use case: "Selling subscriptions"

Child uses cases:

- "Self buy a subscription"
- "Sell subscription to someone else"
- etc

My question is: is it correct to have 2 different actors (customer and vendor) linked to the parent use case in the top level use case diagram, but each of them linked to only one child use case in a more detailed use case diagram or there is something i do wrong ?

Comment: parent use case naming is incorrect. It should be "Sell subscription"

Answer (score 0):

The two actors should be linked to the primary parent use case.

Then in your detailed use case diagram you can do the specific link to the secondary use cases.

*(If that doesn't answer your question please provide us a diagram with what you want to do)*